# Why emacs doesn't load my .emacs at the begining

Tags: emacs

On a computer I have emacs installed. I wanted to install emacs on another computer without administrator rights.

So I copied all the directory from the computer on which emacs is already installed to the other computer. I add the .emacs with C-x f ~/.emacs

When I open emacs again the file .emacs is not read and there is an error message :

mapc: Opening directory: No such file or directory, C:/Program Files/GNU Emacs 26.1/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d

I know emacs is not installed there. (this is the path where emacs was installed on the computer from where I copied the directory)

How can I say to emacs the right path when it opens?

Comment: Looks like you are on Windows. Can you indicate which Emacs exactly you installed, and how?

Comment: Does the folder C:/Program Files/GNU Emacs 26.1/share/emacs/site-lisp/site-start.d really exist on the target computer? Perhaps there was a problem during the copy

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `.emacs` file does in fact get loaded but that something in there causes the error you see. After that error, the rest of the file does not get evaluated.

I suggest bisecting your `.emacs` file until you're identified the culprit: delete half of your `.emacs` file and see if the error persists. If so, delete half of that, and so on, until you get to a point where everything works. Then add in half of the last half you deleted, and so on, until you get to the part that causes the error.